# Why the modifier of field of a same Class can be different when loaded by different Class Loader?

Tags: java, classloader

[image: I read it from this link https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Class_Loading_and_Types_in_Java-LinkageErrors___Making_Sure_You_Are_Who_You_Say_You_Are.html#:~:text=Loading%20constraints%20validate%20type%20expectations,for%20user%20defined%20class%20loaders.&text=There%20are%20two%20type%20of%20class%20loaders%2C%20initiating%20and%20defining.]

I don't understand the example in that paper.
Link:https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Class_Loading_and_Types_in_Java-LinkageErrors___Making_Sure_You_Are_Who_You_Say_You_Are.html#:~:text=Loading%20constraints%20validate%20type%20expectations,for%20user%20defined%20class%20loaders.&text=There%20are%20two%20type%20of%20class%20loaders%2C%20initiating%20and%20defining.

Answer (score 2):

The class can be *completely* different if you want to, not just about a field's visibility. Just create two completely different classes, give them the same FQN and load them with different classloaders. You've got "same classes", because they've got the same FQN, but they're in no way compatible.

The excerpt demonstrates that it was possible to use that in 1.1 to access private fields directly because the class checking wasn't strict enough to determine that those classes are in fact not the same class: different classloaders can load different bytecode for the same FQN.